# I/Choreographer: Skipped frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Пытался читать про решение проблемы, но не понимаю, как это связано с моей программой. В LinearLayout с картинкой на фоне я пытаюсь создать vertical ScrollView с последовательными ImageView . Без фона программа работает нормально.
P.S. Ещё не получается выровнять ScrollView по центру экрана
  Вот полный код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bckgr"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scroll_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scroll_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/scroll"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/scroll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: ```android:scaleType``` это параметр для ```ImageView```. Можете удалить его из ```LinearLayout``` и ```ScrollView```.

Answer (score 2):

Ваше сообщение `Skipped xx frames...` значит, что ваше приложение блокирует основной поток на слишком длительное время.
Чтобы выровнять `ScrollView` поцентру, добавьте в корневой `LinearLayout` `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: И как же разблокировать этот поток?
Спасибо за gravity, совсем забыл про неё.

Comment: @ГосподьБомж, перенести тяжелые операции во второстепенный поток.